# Get wrong value when same time enter in php time subtraction

Tags: time, difference

```
$StartTime= '07:00:00';
$EndTime = '07:24:13';
$sst = strtotime($StartTime);
$eet=  strtotime($EndTime);
$diff= $eet-$sst;
echo $timeElapsed= gmdate("h:i:s",$diff);
```

Here the answer must be 24 min and 13 sec, but the result I get is 12:24:13.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$StartTime= '07:00:00';
$EndTime = '07:24:13';
$sst = strtotime($StartTime);
$eet=  strtotime($EndTime);
$diff= $eet-$sst;
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $diff);
```

There's a typo in your code, H must be in uppercase.